# How can I get the shape of a Road Element using the Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to highlight a specific section of a road on my map. The user should be able to click on a map and using the Location of the click, I want to highlight the closest road element.

In the Here Android SDK, the [RoadElement](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/RoadElement.html#getRoadElement-com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate-java.lang.String-) can do exactly what I want: I can pass some coordinates and use `getGeometry()` to obtain the exact shape of the road element.

However, I couldn't find something similar to this in the javascript SDK. I tried using Reverse Geocoding:

```
  var geocodingParams = {
    lat: road.lat,
    lng: road.lng,
    mode: 'retrieveAddresses',
    maxresults: '1',
    additionaldata: ['IncludeShapeLevel', 'postalCode'],
    prox: road.lat + ',' + road.lng
  };

  this.geoCodingService.reverseGeocode(geocodingParams, onResult, null);
```

This way, I can find the closest road, but I don't get accurate shape data. In the Results View, there is only the Bounding Box (Location.MapView.BottomRight and Location.MapView.TopLeft).

How can I achieve something similar to the RoadElements, using the Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

Our routing APIs return the shape points along a route. So given a set of start and stop waypoints the JavaScript SDK routing API will give the route shape. 
Example code is included on this page:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/routing.html

Another alternative will be to use the Advanced fleet telematics API and look into the datasets yourself.